# Problem with the Android unirest library - static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier

Tags: android, unirest, mashape

I'm using the mashape unirest lirary to make POST HTTP calls in android, but when I tried to get the response I'm getting the issue

> No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier

I think the issue is with the default HTTP library that Android uses and with the unirest, but I couldn't find a way to resolve it.

Is there any other way I can make the call or any other libraries I can use.

This is the exception cause

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework